# OpenGL still tries to blur even with GL_NEAREST (GL_TEXTURE_2D)

Tags: opengl

An image says a thousand words, so what about two? I have this map art:

[image: map image]

In order to actually use this as a map I scale this texture 6 times. This however didn't go as expected:

[image: desired-actual]

All the OpenGL code is in my homebrew 2D OpenGL rendering library, and since OpenGL is a state machine it is hard to actually document the whole rendering process. But here is +/- what I do (the code is Python):

```
width, height = window.get_size()
glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()

glOrtho(0.0, width, height, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()

# displacement trick for exact pixelization
glTranslatef(0.375, 0.375, 0.0)

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

glEnable(self.texture.target) # GL_TEXTURE_2D
glBindTexture(self.texture.target, self.texture.id)

glTexParameteri(self.texture.target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(self.texture.target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

glPushMatrix()

glTranslatef(self.x, self.y, 0.0) # self.x and self.y are negative int offsets
glScalef(self.scale_x, self.scale_y, 1.0) # scale_x and scale_y are both 6

glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glTexCoord2i(0, 0)
glVertex2i(0, 0)
glTexCoord2i(0, 1)
glVertex2i(0, self.texture.height)
glTexCoord2i(1, 1)
glVertex2i(self.texture.width, self.texture.height)
glTexCoord2i(self.texture.width, 0)
glVertex2i(self.texture.width, 0)
glEnd()

glPopMatrix()
glDisable(self.texture.target)
```

However, this "blurring" bug doesn't occur when I use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB. I'd like to also be able to use GL_TEXTURE_2D, so can someone please point out how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you using mipmaps at all? What format does the texture come from (compressed or lossless)?

Comment: @peachykeen: The original format is irrelevant, it is first loaded using a codec into a simple RGBA array, after that it is uploaded to OpenGL using SOIL (specifically, `tex.id = SOIL_create_OGL_texture(data, width, height, 4, 0, SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO)`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt - replace your texture with same size black'n'white checkerboard (black/white 1px). It will give you a good sense of what is going - is it going to be uniformly gray (displacement is wrong) or is it going to have waves (scaling is wrong).

Make sure you don't have mip-maps automatically generated and used.

Generally you don't need any special displacement, texels match pixels with properly setup glOrtho.

Another important issue - use PowerOfTwo textures, as older GPU could used various schemes to support NPOT textures (scaling or padding transparently to user) which could result in just that sort of blurring.

To manually work with NPOT textures you will need to pad them with clear pixels till next POT size and scale your UV values `glTextCoord2f(u,v)` by the factor `npotSize / potSize`. Note that this is not compatible with tiling, but judging from your art you don't need it.

Comment: The image data that I upload is not POT, but I pass the flag to SOIL to convert it to POT. (SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO). Here, try imgur: http://i.imgur.com/N60WI.png

Comment: There's you problem. I reckon your checkers texture was not square - thus it has different patters horizontaly and verticaly. Retest with POT checkers texture and remove that SIOL_ flag - it should be working fine then. The trick with your art textures - you will have to pad them to POT manually.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a bug in SOIL. Actually removing the SOIL POT flag fixes the problem altogether. Reading through the SOIL source code I see that if you omit the POT flag it will automatically check if the video card supports NPOT textures and otherwise convert anyway. Mine does, so I suspect that the SOIL routine for converting to a POT texture is bugged. That settled, how should I convert my own textures to POT dynamically? Just append completely translucent pixels to the offending side(s) of the texture?

Comment: As it seems you have already answered my question of my previous comment in your answer, thanks. Could you finally (before I obviously accept your answer) explain what UV values are?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> # displacement trick for exact pixelization
> glTranslatef(0.375, 0.375, 0.0)
> ```

Unfortunately this is not enough since you also need to scale the texture. For a unscaled, untranslated texture matrix, to address a certain pixel *i* from a texture with dimension *N* you need to apply the formula

```
(2i + 1)/(2N)
```

You can derive your scaling and translation from that – or determine the texture coordinates directly.

#### EDIT due to comment.

Okay, let's say your texture is 300 pixels wide, and you want to address exactly pixels 20 to 250, then the texture coordinates to choose for a identity texture matrix  would be

```
(2*20 + 1)/(2*300) = 41/600 = 0.0650
```

and

```
(2*250 + 1)/(2*300) = 501/600 = 0.8350
```

But you could apply a transformation through the texture matrix as well. You want to map the pixels 0…299 (for 300 pixels width the index goes from 0 to 300-1 = 299) to 0…1. So let's put in those figures:

```
(2*0 + 1)/(2*300) =  1/600 =~= 0.0017 = a
(2*299 + 1)/(2*300) = 599/600 =~= 0.9984 = b

b-a =~= 0.9967
```

So you have to scale down the range 0…1 by 0.9967 and offset it by 0.0017 in the width. The same calculation goes for the height←→t coordinates. Remember that order of transformations matters. You must first scale then translate when performing the transformation, so in the matrix multiplications the translation is multiplied first:

```
// for a texture 300 pixels wide
glTranslatef(0.0017, …, …);
glScale(0.9967, …, …);
```

If you want use pixels instead of the range 0…1, further divide the scale by the texture width.

**A BIG HOWEVER:**

OpenGL-3 completely discarded the whole matrix manipulation functions and expect you to supply it ready to use matrices and shaders. And for OpenGL fragment shaders there is a nice function `texelFetch` which you can use to directly fetch texture pixels with absolute coordinates. Using that would make things *a lot* easier!

Comment: I tried really hard, but I have no idea how to turn this into some code. Could you please explain some more?

Comment: This is wrong answer. Note that provided images are not zoomed, they are rendered at x6, and note that pixel interpolation is not uniform (door right side and windows right sides). Something messed the texture in first place (probably NPOT -> POT conversion on GPU)

Comment: @Krom: Hmm, you could be right. Maybe the OP used gluBuildMipmaps2D…

Comment: @datenwolf: I guess his OpenGL implementation is rather unusual in this part `tex.id = SOIL_create_OGL_texture`. Maybe there are other `SOIL_` parts that apply influence.

Comment: @Krom: SOIL is a texture uploading library: www.lonesock.net/soil.html